# The five logging levels in logging module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read [logging — Logging facility for Python — Python 3.7.3rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and find there are 6 kinds of log level are defined

```
| Level      | Numeric value |
| ---------- | ------------- |
| `CRITICAL` | 50            |
| `ERROR`    | 40            |
| `WARNING`  | 30            |
| `INFO`     | 20            |
| `DEBUG`    | 10            |
| `NOTSET`   | 0             |
```

Upon referring to linux `syslog` ,8 kinds are definded

[syslog(2) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html)

```
The log level
       Every printk() message has its own log level.  If the log level is
       not explicitly specified as part of the message, it defaults to
       default_message_loglevel.  The conventional meaning of the log level
       is as follows:

       Kernel constant   Level value   Meaning
       KERN_EMERG                       0        System is unusable
       KERN_ALERT                        1        Action must be taken immediately
       KERN_CRIT                           2        Critical conditions
       KERN_ERR                             3        Error conditions
       KERN_WARNING                 4        Warning conditions
       KERN_NOTICE                      5        Normal but significant condition
       KERN_INFO                           6        Informational
       KERN_DEBUG                      7        Debug-level messages

       The kernel printk() routine will print a message on the console only
       if it has a log level less than the value of console_loglevel.
```

Additionally, SSH defined 8 kinds as well

SSH LogLevel

[sshd_config(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5))

```
  LogLevel
         Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from
         sshd(8).  The possible values are: 
         QUIET,
         FATAL, 
         ERROR, 
         INFO,
         VERBOSE,
         DEBUG, 
         DEBUG1, 
         DEBUG2, 
         and DEBUG3.  The default is INFO.
         DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify
         higher levels of debugging output.  Logging with a DEBUG level
         violates the privacy of users and is not recommended.
```

Where does the definitions of the five kinds logging level originate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that the `logging` module lets you define additional levels if you need to, and that the missing ones are rather specific to the domains of the tools whose documentation you are referring to.

"Quiet" is identical to disabling `logging` entirely and a "fatal" error would presumably be one where your Python program has to terminate. If you want additional debugging levels in a particular application of yours, go ahead and define them - though a better approach might be to just use `logging.DEBUG` for everything, and instead selectively enable or disable debug-level `logging` for individual submodules in your system.